# How to use base R function using data subsetted with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, subset

Say I have these data:

```
testdata <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("a", "b", "b"))
```

I want to use the base R `table` command to get a tally of the variable `b`, but after subsetting based on `a`'s values. Importantly, I want to subset using tidyverse in one line. Here is an attempt that doesn't work; I am not sure how to get it to correctly refer to column `b`.

```
table(testdata %>% filter(a<3) $ b)
```

Note this is how I would do it in two steps:

```
testdata2 <- testdata %>% filter(a<3)
table(testdata2$b)
```

Comment: It's pretty ugly, but you can use the same old `$` syntax, like `table((testdata %>% filter(a < 3))$b)` The issue was you were trying to subset `filter(a<3)` instead of the entire expression surrounded by `(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pull` to extract the column and then apply the `table`

```
library(dplyr)
testdata %>% 
     filter(a<3) %>%
     pull(b) %>% 
     table
```

-output

```
a b 
1 1
```

---

Or use `base R` with `|>` operator (from `R 4.1.0` onwards)

```
subset(testdata, a < 3, select = b) |> 
      table()

a b 
1 1
```

As we are already using `dplyr`, why not use `count`

```
testdata %>%
    filter(a < 3) %>%
    count(b)
```